# inject parent javascript files inside ajax child

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

the story: 
I use ajax a lot inside a certain project, I build floating divs and populate them with different content using ajax (similar with how facebook works when using the popups).

The problem I have is when getting an ajax page I need to reinclude all javascript inside that page in order for the javascript functions to work properly.

In short when I output the ajax content i do again the `<script src='..` things

The big problem is that this slows down the application as there are additionally calls for the javascript files that are already included in the parent window.

How do you handle this issue? Thank you!

Comment: `when getting an ajax page I need to reinclude all javascript` do you load javascript code by ajax?

Comment: the question is unclear . If you are building popup like divs (like facebook does , i think (? not sure , i dont use fb)) , there wont be a need to include the re-include the js files already loaded . If you are using new popup windows , then files should be re-included .

Comment: Are you actually using iFrames instead of AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when getting an ajax page I need to reinclude all javascript inside that page in order for the javascript functions to work properly…

> How do you handle this issue?

What issue? If you are about handlers that you’ve attached to an events of dynamically added objects, then, in case of using jquery, your best bet would be livequery plugin.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I was unclear. Let's say I have an ajax call that gets a page inside a div. This page loaded with ajax, has a lot of elements  that use  javascript/ajax too. To work well inside  the page requested by ajax I include again all  the javascript files from the parent. Is there a way not to request the same javascript files twice?  I can not use live from jquery because there are not simple bind events but I am using other jquery plugins for instance.

Comment: I give a more simpler example: let's say you use a jquery plugin like any carousel out there. If you load a page with ajax that uses the jquery plugin it won't work properly without reincluding all the javascript files...   What can I do to stop requesting the javascript files again?

Comment: A block of code with your issue would tell much more then any description. Really, I still don’t understand what the issue is. Can you provide an example? I would gladly help.

Comment: It was an old question which was not clear enough. The approach I did to dynamic inject javascript is different but of course jquery on off handlers are a good solution nowadays